# Shortening Twitter button follower number

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter

I'm using Twitter buttons on a website i'm designing and next to the "Follow" button, it shows the number of followers the user has. My problem is that the length of the follower number that it's showing is 5,902, instead of 5.9k. Is there any way to do this with the Twitter API?

Thanks in advance.